# Intel C++ Compiler can't find stdio.h

Tags: c++

I am trying to build my code using the Intel C++ Compiler, but for some reason it fails with this error:

> catastrophic error: cannot open source file "stdio.h"

In this line `#include <stdio.h>`.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's also a system header file so it *would* be `#include <stdio.h>` or `#include <cstdio>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: С++ does not have `stdio.h`, use `cstdio` instead. Also, use `<>` instead of `""` for system headers.

Comment: C++ does have `stdio.h` (there are good reasons to prefer `cstdio`, though.

Comment: Sorry, I put <studio.h> but it has been corrected, so it's not that, put it with "<>"

Answer (score 0):

`stdio.h` is a standard header file; it's a bad idea to have a local file of the same name.  If you meant to include the standard header, it should be on your include path, and you should include it with

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

You should also consider whether you might get more benefit from including `<iostream>` or including `<cstdio>` (like including `<stdio.h>`, but puts the symbols safely into the `std` namespace).

Comment: Sorry, I put <studio.h> but it has been corrected, so it's not that, I put it correctly with "<>"

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on Windows, then installing Visual Studio, then invoking "psxevars.bat" might solve your problem, it solved it for me.